# Binding expression cannot contain chained expression (Angular 8)

Tags: angular, parsing

I need to add -webkit and -moz among other browser support

```
[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'}; 
{'-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'}; 
{'-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'};
{'-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'};
{'-o-transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'};"
```

However, the above code is throwing an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at column 71 in ...
```

What could be the possible solution to get out of this?

It works only if I have one value that is:

```
[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)'};"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to put all your style binding in one object as opposed to a new object for each style, e.g:

```html
[ngStyle]="{
  'transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)',
  '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)',
  '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)',
  '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)',
  '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + ((result.percentage * 1.8) - 90) + 'deg)',
}"
```